# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}_+$ can be enumerated as $(q_n)$ such that $\lim\sqrt[n]{q_n}$ exists.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, rational-numbers

> Prove that the set of positive rationals can be enumerated as $(q_n),$ such that $\lim\sqrt[n]{q_n}$ exists.

*Comment.* I don't know if I should be looking for a certain "formula" on $q_n's$, or a way, a method to enumerate the positive rationals, in order to get the desired result.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is a cool question. I haven't done it before but I doubt you should be trying to think of a formula. Probably more like thinking of directly enumerating the rationals "one-by-one" (just like that basic proof of their countability) so that it is easy to 'see' that the limit exists.

Comment: An idea to perhaps get started is this: Try to walk along the rationals, going back and forth about zero, such that on the $k^{th}$ pass, you enumerate rationals with denominator equal to $k$ and absolute value at most $k$. Except don't keep returning to zero, that's bad.

Comment: If the limit exists, then it should be $1$ since there are infinitely many terms below $1$ and infinitely many terms above $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{Q}_{+} = \bigcup_{k = 1}^{\infty} Q_k$ with disjoint finite nonempty $Q_k$ such that $Q_k \subseteq [1/k, k]$;
$$\text{say, take }Q_k=\{a/b : a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}, a + b = k + 1, \gcd(a, b) = 1\}.$$
Now if, say, $Q_k=\{q_{n_k}, \ldots, q_{n_{k + 1} - 1}\}$ with $n_1 = 1$, then

- $n \mapsto q_n$ is an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}_{+}$;
- $n_{k} \geqslant k$ (because $Q_k$ is nonempty for all $k$);
- $(1/k)^{1/k} \leqslant q_n^{1/n} \leqslant k^{1/k}$ when $n_k \leqslant n < n_{k + 1}$.

As $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty} k^{1/k} = 1$, the last inequality implies $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n^{1/n} = 1$.